# Increment decimal but right position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a voting system and what I have done so far is:

```js
$('#Up').click(function() {
  var rate = $('#Rate').text();
  var math = parseInt(rate) + 1;

  $('#Rate').text(math.toFixed(1));

});

$('#Down').click(function() {
  var rate = $('#Rate').text();
  var math = parseInt(rate) - 1;

  $('#Rate').text(math.toFixed(1));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Up">Up Vote</button>
<div id="Rate">0</div>
<button id="Down">Down Vote</button>
```

I want to when to push up or down vote button the number increase or decrease in decimal format but change right position of the decimal. Ex:

Increment like this: (order by upvote)

```
0.1 => 0.2 = > 0.3 => 0.4 => 0.5 => 0.6 => 0.7 => 0.8 => 0.9 => 1.0 => 1.1 => 1.2
```

What I tried change left the position of decimal, but I want to change right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adjusting the values by whole numbers and using `parseInt()`, adjust them by the decimal and use `parseFloat()`.

Also, there is no need for two functions here, since they only differ by the amount they are using to adjust by. Just use one function and pass the desired increment/decrement to it. Anytime you find yourself writing code that you've already written, stop and think about how you can refactor the code to avoid that. Duplicate code swells the code base, doesn't scale well and is more difficult to debug.

Lastly, it is a best-practice to set your variables to DOM objects (or, in the case of JQuery, sets of DOM objects), rather than specific properties of objects (like `.text()`) because if you wind up needing a different property of the same object later, you have to re-query the DOM for the object reference. And, it is common convention that when you reference a JQuery object that you prefix it with `$` to remind you and others that it's not a DOM object reference but a JQuery reference.

```js
var $rate = $('#Rate');

var result = null; // This is the variable that will store the most recent value

$('#Up').on("click", function(){ adjust(.1) });
$('#Down').on("click", function(){ adjust(-.1) });

function adjust(val){
  result = (parseFloat($rate.text()) + val).toFixed(1);
  $rate.text(result);
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Up">Up Vote</button>
<div id="Rate">0</div>
<button id="Down">Down Vote</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Actually all answers here works good and i up voted all, but i'm going to store this votes on database via ajax, so i think the best choice is your answer, because it used one function, but i tried to get result on a variable, like `var result = (parseFloat($rate.text()) + val).toFixed(1); alert(result);` but it return wrong number, add this line to your function to see what i mean, how to fix this?

Comment: @tourtravel I have updated the answer to reflect the last value being stored in a variable and am logging that variable to show that it works. Most likely you were declaring the variable inside your function, which wipes it out every time the function runs and gives the variable only function scope, so it can't be accessed outside of the function. By declaring the variable outside of the function, its scope is accessible to other code you have.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `Number()` to convert string to number.
2. increment/decrement by `0.1`

```js
$('#Up').click(function() {
  var rate = $('#Rate').text();
  var math = Number(rate) + 0.1;

  $('#Rate').text(math.toFixed(1));

});

$('#Down').click(function() {
  var rate = $('#Rate').text();
  var math = Number(rate) - 0.1;

  $('#Rate').text(math.toFixed(1));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Up">Up Vote</button>
<div id="Rate">0</div>
<button id="Down">Down Vote</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, just try to parse it as `float` instead of `int`;

```js
$('#Up').click(function() {
  var rate = $('#Rate').text();
  var math = parseFloat(rate) + 0.1;

  $('#Rate').text(math.toFixed(1));

});

$('#Down').click(function() {
  var rate = $('#Rate').text();
  var math = parseFloat(rate) - 0.1;

  $('#Rate').text(math.toFixed(1));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Up">Up Vote</button>
<div id="Rate">0</div>
<button id="Down">Down Vote</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is store the rate as data attribute. JQuery `data()` will automatically cast numerical values to number

```js
$('#Up').click(function() {
  adjustRate(.1);
});

$('#Down').click(function() {
  adjustRate(-.1);
});

var $rate = $('#Rate');

function adjustRate(val) { 
  $rate.text(($rate.data().rate += val).toFixed(1));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Up">Up Vote</button>
<div id="Rate" data-rate="0">0</div>
<button id="Down">Down Vote</button>
```